# Looping over a list, consisting nodes and moving turtle on those nodes

Tags: netlogo

I have gis netlogo model with road network. I have looped over the gis feature list and created vertices (nodes) on the roads. Then I have created some turtles and placed them on some of those nodes. The turtles are suppose to move to a final destination (node). using the nw: turtles-on-weighted-path-to function the nodes connecting to the final destination (node) is found. This is stored on turtles-own variable called commute-path.
i.e ask turtle 50[show commute-path]
output:
(turtle 50):[(vertex 4308) vertex(4309) vertex(4313) ... vertex(4716)]

The issue arises when i try to iterate over the list (commute-path) and try to move the turtles from one node to another. i.e vertex 4308 to vertex 4309 and finally to vertex 4716.

I have used a simple for loop as shown below but i get the following error "this code cant be run by the turtle, only the observer error while resc agent 7181 running_DONE called by button go"

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks

```
turtles-own (commute-path)
to go

ask turtles[
foreach commute-path[
i ->
move-to i
]
]
```

Comment: Can you show some more of your code? I don't see a problem with what you've shown, so long as commute path stores only agents. Is the output from `show commute-path` exactly as shown in the observer?

Comment: Hi Luke. Thanks for getting back to me . I figured this problem out. The issue was that road network I imported from gis which has some roads  not connecting to other roads. And if a turtle was to spawn on one of the road vertices which are not connected. Nw:turtles-on-path-to function would fail as they would not be able to connect